# Add an array to array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two variables which is an array and array of object, I want to add the value of first variable(distance) to second variable(list)

The following works fine, but I want to know if there's any other method to get some result.

```js
let distance = [100,200,300]
let list = [ {"city" : "paris"} , {"city" : "london"} , { "city" : "barcelona" }]
for(let i = 0; i < distance.length;i++){
  let listDistance = list.map(el => {
      return Object.assign({}, el, {distance:distance[i++]})
      return el
  });

console.log(listDistance) 
}


// output [ {city : paris , distance : 100 } , {city : london  , distance : 200 } , { city : barcelona , distance : 300 }]
```

Comment: You don't need for loop. Just use the second parameter index from `map`'s callback

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's "How can I improve my code" kind of question therefore, it's more suitable here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: make sure that you aware of the sync/async behavior of JS

Comment: I made you a snippet. Your code does not work. You have a for loop AND a map and you console.log an unknown object. Anyway you have several answers now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```js
let distance = [100,200,300]
let list = [ {"city" : "paris"} , {"city" : "london"} , { "city" : "barcelona" }]

list.forEach((city,i) => city.distance = distance[i])

console.log(list)
```

Older browsers

```js
let distance = [100,200,300]
let list = [ {"city" : "paris"} , {"city" : "london"} , { "city" : "barcelona" }]

list.forEach(function(city,i) { city.distance = distance[i] })

console.log(list)
```

If you need a new Array you can use map:

```js
const distance = [100,200,300]
let list = [ {"city" : "paris"} , {"city" : "london"} , { "city" : "barcelona" }]

let distList = list.map((city,i) => ({ ...city, distance : distance[i]}) )

console.log(distList)
```

Comment: I like your second approach :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
  let array1 = [100, 200, 300]
  let array2 = [{ "city": "paris" }, { "city": "london" }, { "city": "barcelona" }]
  let res = array2.map((value, index) => {
    return { ...value, distance: array1[index] }
  })
  console.log(res);
```

Comment: @mplungjan well can do it in both ways, So I preferred create new array instead of modifying existing one.

Comment: `(=>)` arrow functions are not supported in IE <11!

Comment: There are some alternatives for the same, so coders will have to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(let i = 0; i < distance.length; i++)
{
   list[i].distance = distance[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const listWithDistances = list.map(
  (item, index) => ({ ...item, distance: distance[index] })
)
```

This has the same result of your example of returning a new `Array` of new `Object`s.